# Countdown pause button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdown

When the pause button is clicked the countdown stops. However when the start button is clicked the countdown resets to either the Pomodoro, short break or long break. I understand that it has to do with saving the current time in `timer_start()` as a global variable and feeding that into `myTimer()` but I am still left clueless as to how to do this. Please can someone help me figure this out I am going insane!?
[image]

```
var timer = {
  pomodoro: 25,
  longBreak: 15,
  shortBreak: 5
}
var currentTimerType = timer.pomodoro;
var currentDate = new Date();

function timer_pomodoro() {
   currentTimerType = timer.pomodoro;
   document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = '25';
   document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = '00';
   clearInterval(x);
}
function timer_short() {
  currentTimerType = timer.shortBreak;
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = '5';
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = '00';
  clearInterval(x);
}
function timer_long() {
  currentTimerType = timer.longBreak;
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = '15';
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = '00';
  clearInterval(x);
}

var minutesToAdd = 0;

function timer_start() {
  switch(currentTimerType) {
    case timer.pomodoro:
      minutesToAdd=25;
      break;
    case timer.shortBreak:
      minutesToAdd=5;
      break;
    case timer.longBreak:
      minutesToAdd=15;
      break;
  }

  var currentDate = new Date();
  var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + minutesToAdd*60000);
  countDownDate = futureDate;
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = '00';
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutesToAdd;
  x = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
}

  function myTimer() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;

  if (seconds == 0 & minutes == 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
  }
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(x);
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72685356/edit) and create a [mre] using the `<>` button.

Comment: Also: replace `currentTimerType = timer.pomodoro;` with `currentTimerType = "pomodoro";` (same for the others) and use `minutesToAdd = timer[currentTimerType];` instead of the switch block.

Comment: Here's my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/a5dqfvgL/